# How to center a time series

Tags: probability, statistics, covariance, time-series

So, I was recently asked to study on how to center a time series, been checking online but couldn't find anything related to the topic. Can somebody point me out to where I can get information on this topic or is their another name it goes by. I was asked to study it along with covariance so I'm guessing the question has to do with covariance.

Comment: Does “center” just mean subtracting the mean of all the data points, so that the mean of the new points is zero? I know in machine learning, to “center and scale” data is to transform each feature by subtracting its mean (center) and multiply it by some scale factor.

Comment: @Joe that's probably it, so for a time series, is the centering different from the normal centering of a set of data

Comment: I believe its the same - subtract the sample mean from each point. On page 444 of "Time Series Analysis with applications in R" by Cryer and Chan, it states, "the fitted model is in the centered form; that is, an ARMA model fitted to the series minus its sample mean